# Setting width inside onTouchListener

Tags: java, android, parameters, width, ontouchlistener

I know my onTouchListener is working because rangeL.setX(rawX-width/20) dynamically moves my view, but I'm not getting anything when trying to set width using paramsRange.width inside the listener as shown in the code. The first call to paramsRange.width works though. Any ideas?

```
final LayoutParams paramsRange = rangeView.getLayoutParams();
    paramsRange.height = height;
    paramsRange.width = rangeWidth;
    rangeView.setX(width/10);

    rangeL.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int rawX;
            final int actionIndex = event.getAction() >> MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            final int location[] = { 0, 0 };
            v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            rawX = (int) event.getX(actionIndex) + location[0];
            rangeL.setX(rawX-width/20);

            rangeView.setX(width/10+(rawX-width/20));

            paramsRange.width = rangeWidth-(rawX-width/20);

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `invalidate()` rangeL's parent view end of OnTouchListener.

Comment: rangeL is the child of a realtive layout, so I tried adding the following code just before "return false;"       RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
                relativeLayout.invalidate(); - it's still the same result.

Comment: I finally got the result I needed using requestLayout() instead of invalidate() in the same position. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to find your view height and width, and put it on onResume method. Well, if it don't work, tried put it on onStart method.

```
rangeView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
rangeView.getMeasuredWidth();
rangeView.getMeasuredHeight();
```